Change resolution for RealVNC viewer remote connection
I am using RealVNC viewer to connect to my VM. It is set at 1920x1080 screen resolution. I want to change it to 2560x1440. Anyone know how I can do this? I have server running on VM -

And from my laptop, I am connecting using RealVNC viewer.

I tried the steps mentioned at Setting display resolution beyond 1024x768 with headless Windows 10? but it did not work.
